# Searching for empty string in SphinxQL

Tags: sphinx, sphinxql

I have a string field 'extra_data' in Sphinx index, which has data in comma-separated format (ex. 'green', 'red', 'green,red', ...). And I need to select to find rows:
1. extra_data is 'green'
2. or extra_data is 'red'
3. or extra_data is empty

So I can write query:

```
SELECT id FROM sphinx WHERE MATCH('@extra_data (^green$|^red$))')
```

But how should I write query to find empty extra_data ('') too?

Answer (score 1):

Sphinx doesnt 'index' nothing. It indexes words :)

So you have to arrange for empty to be a *word* that can be indexed.

eg for a database backed index..

```
sql_query = SELECT id,title, ... , IF(extra_data='','_empty',extra_data) AS extra_data FROM mytable ...
```

Then can do

```
... WHERE MATCH('@extra_data (^green$|^red$|_empty)')
```